# Difference between getSize() and count() on collection

Tags: product, magento-1, collection

I have heard many times that they both are the same. But I am facing a weird issue, in the product collection of CatalogSearch module, count() is returning correct product count while getSize() is returning zero.

So, basically this is what I am getting:

```
$collection->count(); //correct count
$collection->getSize(); //0
```

But I want the getSize() to have correct count as it decides whether to show pagination and products in the search page or not. I am using Inner Join, Left Join and Where condition only in the collection to be more specific.

Any ideas why I am getting this weird issue?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

My previous question, [How to clone the collection in Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/how-to-clone-the-collection-in-magento) I wanted to perform two different operations on one collection. The first collection shows correct getSize(), but then if the getSize() is zero, I removed the WHERE clause and gave new WHERE condition. After this, I am getting correct raw SQL what I expected, and running it in MySQL also gives a correct set of records, but only getSize() on the collection is giving zero counts.

So basically I may need to reload the collection, as getSize() is taking old count. Makes sense?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Most (if not all) the collections extend `Varien_Data_Collection_Db`. Here are the 2 methods from this class

```
public function getSize()
{
    if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
        $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
        $this->_totalRecords = $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql, $this->_bindParams);
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
} 

public function count() //inherited from Varien_Data_Collection
{
    $this->load();
    return count($this->_items);
}
```

There is a difference. For `getSize()` the collection is not loaded. For `count()` it is.
Usually collection models use the same `getSize()` method as above and only override `getSelectCountSql()`.
In `getSelectCountSql()` the limit is reset in order to get the total number of records available for the set filters (`where` statement).
See how the `getSelectCountSql()` works

```
public function getSelectCountSql()
{
    $this->_renderFilters();
    $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
    $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');
    return $countSelect;
}
```

Comment: Great! So what should be my next step to reload the collection so that it can get correct `getSize()`?  Thanks!

Comment: I honestly don't know why do you get this result. In the `CatalogSearch` module there is nothing that overrides `getSize()` or `getSelectCountSql()`. It should work by default, unless you added some custom code. Can you post the way you build the collection?

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: There is no way to reset `_totalRecords`. You can try to clone the collection before calling `getSize()` on the original collection. Maybe that will work.

Comment: you can also do something like this to get a "reset" count: `$sql = $collection->getSelectCountSql(); return $collection->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql);`

Answer (score 14):

## Be careful. This is correct, but the methods are overwritten in `Varien_Data_Collection_Db` as described by Marius

Just have a look into

```
// \Varien_Data_Collection::getSize
public function getSize()
{
    $this->load();
    if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
        $this->_totalRecords = count($this->getItems());
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}

// \Varien_Data_Collection::count
public function count()
{
    $this->load();
    return count($this->_items);
}
```

So it should on this low level be the same. Both methods load the collection and count the items.

**UPDATE**

Oh I see a problem: getSize() caches the _totalRecords, this means it is not recalculated. Check where `_totalRecords` is set?

Comment: Yes I have looked at it, but can't figure it out why both are generating different counts for the same collection? Any ideas how to reload collection or something to get correct count in `getSize()`?

Comment: updated the entry

Comment: `getSize()` does not load the collection for records that come from the data base. Not unless you override the method and tell it to load the collection.

Comment: _totalRecords is protected so can't call it in my custom file with collection. `echo count($collection->load()->getItems());` gives correct count, but again I want `getSize()` to work.

Answer (score 6):

This answer shows up in google for "magento getSize wrong" and similar searches so I would like to add a possible scenario that might be useful to someone

When you have a group statement in your query and you do a

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) ... GROUP BY ( at_id_art.value )
```

Mysql will return a count for EACH of the groups, so Varien_Data_Collection_Db::getSize() will return the wrong answer, this is because this function fetches the first row:

```
public function getSize()
{
    if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
        $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
        $this->_totalRecords = $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql, $this->_bindParams);
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}
```

When it populates

```
$this->_totalRecords = $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql, $this->_bindParams);
```

It selects the first row and therefore returns the total of the first group as the total size.

I ended up coming up with this code to count, based on the unique values of the attributes in my query.

```
$select = clone $collection->getSelect();
$group = $select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
$select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)->columns("COUNT(DISTINCT {$group[0]})");
$totalCount = $collection->getConnection()->fetchOne($select);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you end up here, there is another simple fix to try:

```
System -> Index Management
```

and select them all (even if they are indicating "Green, no re-index needed" and force them to reindex.

This solved my empty `getSize()` problem, which in turn, allowed the Special and New database requests to find the products, fulfill the "if" conditions and properly render.

Answer (score 0):

When `count($collection)` was different than `$collection->getSize()` I had to `reindex` the products, then everything worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

There is a main difference For getSize() the product collection is not loaded. For count() it will load whole product collection. 
So for big catalog it is not advisable to use count function in any collection.

Comment: Already said in Marius post ...