# Why getSize() function is not working when apply filter

Tags: orders, configurable-product, collection, varien

I want to get count after the collection filter by attributes.Actually i want filter order collections `by non canceled ,non fraud`' and use `getSize()` function to get count but it is given `count result` as  when `any filters not applied`.

Please suggest what i do `in this case`to get proper result of count.I have order 630  and when i use `count()` function on collection filter it give proper result.

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

echo $orderCollection->getSize().'---'; // Result 630
                //$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer->getId());
$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('state', array('nin' => array('pending_payment', 'canceled', 'fraud', 'payment_review', 'pending', 'pending_paypal', 'closed')));

echo $orderCollection->size(); // result give 630


echo $orderCollection->count(); // given 305  proper result.
```

I guess that  may load() function is working for `getCount()` that why it is ok.
 I have check the link [Difference between getSize() and count() on collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4036/difference-between-getsize-and-count-on-collection)

**My question, is  my concept is right?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you call `getSize()` twice and you modify the collection between the calls.
Take a look at how `getSize()` works.

```
public function getSize()
{
    if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
        $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
        $this->_totalRecords = $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql, $this->_bindParams);
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}
```

So the first time you call `getSize()` you get the correct result 630.
Then you add an other filter to the collection and call `getSize()` again.
But the first time you call `getSize()` the value is remembered in `$this->_totalRecords`.
the second time you call it, the query is not executed again because `$this->_totalRecords` is not null and the method just returns the value you have already set, 630 in your case.

You can remove the first `getSize()`call if you don't need it.
If you need it you can do this:

```
//clone the collection object
$clone = clone $orderCollection;
//get the total size from the clone
echo $clone->getSize();
//add the filter to the original object
$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('state', array('nin' => array('pending_payment', 'canceled', 'fraud', 'payment_review', 'pending', 'pending_paypal', 'closed')));
//get the size of the filtered collection
echo $orderCollection->size();
```

Comment: i am so stupid.. it did not check..that.... saw reference but did not proper..... Thank You marius :) accept + 1 upvote

Comment: i have lock for 5 min for accept the answe