# Not getting NULL value or empty value when the filter fails.Why?

Tags: orders, collection

I am using the code below to get the orders when filtering using email address of the logged in user.

```
$order = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
        ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
return $order;
```

But if the user has not placed an order at all then $order should be NULL value or empty value right? but I am not getting an empty value which I found out after using `print_r($order);`.

I need empty or null value so that I can display a notification to the customer to tell him that he has not ordered anything. if there is a way to get NULL value then please explain.

Comment: Where do you call this?

Comment: Inside a method in the Block file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per object OOPS concept,$order is object,so you cannot get null value from object.

In this case you can use `getSize()` function because it give `no of record of a collection`.It is give `Varien collection` object and it give `value as false` whenever a collection does not have records.

```
if(!$order->getSize()){
// no order available for  customer
}
```

How to use getSize( see at  [Why getSize() function is not working when apply filter](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65336/why-getsize-function-is-not-working-when-apply-filter)

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to reinvent the wheel. If you don't know how to do - look how it resolved by magento.

If you want to check if order exist - firstly look how does magento determines that. As example:

> Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController::_initOrder()

```
    if (!$order->getId()) {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('This order no longer exists.'));
```

If I want to check any object existing - I always check it's ID and firstly check if this object exists:

```
if ($order && $order->getId()) {
    ...
```