# Efficient way to access current result count in left block

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

Tried a few different approaches to this but still not sure of the best option for something which *should* be relatively simple. I want to output the current product result count, instead of within the toolbar, in the layered navigation (left block).

I realise that I need to use an instance of `catalog/product_list_toolbar` to be able to access `$this->getTotalNum()`, but creating a new block with the same block class doesn't work. I've tried the below but it seems to result in a slower page load and count results inconsistent with what's in the toolbar:

```
<?php $customBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list'); ?>
    <?php echo $customBlock->getLoadedProductCollection()->count(); ?>
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: use  `->getSize()` because `count()` loads entire collection refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4039/45103