# how to write collection query in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, model, sql

i have this custom collection which is taking much time to load, so want to change into sql query how can I achieve it?

```
$delayedcollectioncount = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname, entity_id')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('grisk_college_new_id', array('in' =>$college))
        ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', array('in' => array(4,5)))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('assigned_campus_manager', array('null' => true), 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('physical_verify', array('null' => true), 'left')
        ->addFieldToFilter('grisk_pv_upload_date', array('lt' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($configValue))))
        ->addAttributeToSort('grisk_pv_upload_date', 'DESC')
        ->count();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need a count and there are no limits on your query, you can just replace `count`  with `getSize`.
It should be way faster.
Here are some details about the difference: [Difference between getSize() and count() on collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4036/difference-between-getsize-and-count-on-collection/4039#4039)

Comment: wow !! it worked reduce my loading time !! Thanks man!!! :)

Comment: but still i want to try with query if it can reduce more .

Comment: it may incorrect my counts also ?

Comment: I don't think it will reduce the time much more. Because `getSize` actually runs one single query. and retrieve one single result. the only time you would save would be from bypassing the query builder. But honestly you don't want to do that since the customer model is and EAV model. This means it joins some tables in order to filter by attributes. Writing it as a query increases your error chances significantly.

Comment: loading time i m not able to check in test server perfectly but still, i m getting significant difference , any way just worried about correct count as a  result .