# Magento getCollection()->getSize() giving wrong value

Tags: magento-1.9, php

custom filter of `getLoadedProductCollection()` function,

`getSize()` method does not give correct value

```
$this->getCollection()->getSize()
```

Comment: Can you share the custom filter code

Comment: $_productCollection = $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array(
    array('like' => '%'.$search_txt.'%')
));     where variable $search_txt    is input from user

Comment: where you  try to get count phtml or block class?

Comment: @AlamZaib check my answer I think it will help you.

Comment: use `count()` instead of `getSize()`, for the `getSize()` the collection is not loaded, for `count()` it is. look https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4039/48355

Comment: count() is giving me 30 which is the limit of page, but i am expecting for total result 2

Comment: @Prince using `count()` is bad for performance. See http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Conquer_the_5_Most_Common_Magento_Coding_Issues_to_Optimize_Your_Site_for_Performance.pdf

Comment: @B00MER Yes I agree with you if the `count()` is inside a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
$_productCollection = $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array( array('like' => '%'.$search_txt.'%') ));
```

Clone the collection object

```
$clone = clone $_productCollection;
```

Get the total size from the clone.

```
echo $clone->getSize();
```

Comment: it is not giving me correct number ,

Comment: @AlamZaib past your full code to your question so we can check it and help you.

Comment: Collection are cached, using a clone should reinitiate the cache. However using `getSize()` is correct. See http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Conquer_the_5_Most_Common_Magento_Coding_Issues_to_Optimize_Your_Site_for_Performance.pdf

Answer (score -3):

Please Use -

```
$totalProduct = count($this->getCollection()->getData());
```

Comment: Using count is bad for performance see http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Conquer_the_5_Most_Common_Magento_Coding_Issues_to_Optimize_Your_Site_for_Performance.pdf

Comment: Don't use count() function for count collection data. It will harm your performance if your collection has loaded huge data.