# Magento 2 - Collection getSize() returns zero

Tags: magento2.3, collection

I have read about the [difference between collection count() and collection getSize()](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4036/difference-between-getsize-and-count-on-collection), but I don't understand what's the reason that gives different numbers in each method.

In a custom collection I created, I get the following:

```
echo $collection->getSize(); //returns 0
echo count($collection); //returns 33
```

1) Can somebody help, so I can find what causes zero results in my collection?

2) Does stock management affect with getSize()?

Comment: echo count($collection->getSize());  Use this.

Comment: that doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

In my case, It's because I use Magento 2.4.2 with Elasticsearch 6, But configure in backend use Elasticsearch 7. I just upgrade Elasticsearch to 7. Now getSize work fine. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have ES 7 and using MirasvitSearch but still the getSize method return me 0 results . Any idea ?

Comment: I think you should contact to extension provider (MirasvitSearch).

Answer (score 0):

You can try below to resolved this issue:

> lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php

```
public function getSize()
{
    if ($this->_totalRecords === null) {
    $itemCount = count($this->_items);

    if ($this->_totalRecords === null || ($itemCount > 0 && $itemCount !== $this->_totalRecords)) {
        $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
        $this->_totalRecords = $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql, $this->_bindParams);
        $this->_totalRecords = (int) $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql, $this->_bindParams);
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);

    return (int) $this->_totalRecords;
}
```

Comment: please check your answer again, there are issues with the code syntax

Comment: also, correct path is `vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection\AbstractDb.php`

Comment: code still contains syntax errors and I doesn't solve the issue. Result is zero.

Comment: Can you please let me know which collection you are trying, because i have tried below product collection and working fine:

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
echo count($collection); //result count 89
echo $collection->getSize(); //result count 89

Thanks

Comment: I can't post the collection code, because it's part of extension and passes through many functions to take it's final form. But the final step, collection->getSize() is zero, while count is 33. Do you know what factors make getSize() to exclude products?

Comment: It might be issue with filter which need to find out from your side. because collection return same values for both functions. I can try to solve it but need to check code.