# Trouble fetching current product collection for category without limit

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection, collection-limit

Within my templates category list.phtml I need to pull the full product collection without the page limit. To be clear I do not want to impact the toolbar, pagination, or anything else within category view except for the collection within list.phtml.

I have given [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12045079/1812580) a shot but it impacts pagination as well.

Comment: Not so easy because [cloning collections is not supported](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/how-to-clone-the-collection-in-magento) But it is probably a bad idea anyway, peformance-wise. If you could explain, what you want to achieve, there might be an alternative and better way to achieve it.